# Conflicting error messages for JAX-RS web service

Tags: tomcat, rest, jax-rs

I am developing a RESTful web service using JAX-RS. I am using JAXB to map my classes to the XML that is sent as a request parameter in POST and PUT requests.

To test the functionality of my web service, I wrote a simple client that creates a HttpConnection object and sends the necessary XML to the POST URI. However, this is where I am getting conflicting error messages.

If I use my client, I get an Internal Server Error in response, even though it is not one of the errors I am returning explicitly. Moreover, Tomcat gives no stack trace when I try any kind of request (GET or POST) to explain the cause of the error.

However, if I use curl to send a POST request to the same URI with the same request data, I get an Unsupported media type error (HTTP 415). The media type in both my request as well as the web service handler method is "text/xml".

Can anybody guide me as to how I can troubleshoot this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Troubleshooting REST:** I suggest to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect your traffic. So you can see the exact requests and responses.

**Unsupported media type error (HTTP 415):** When passing xml, you should use `application/xml` or `text/xml` media types.

Comment: Thanks Tarlog for your help. The problem seemed to be that I was casting a Node as an Element which was throwing the exception. Simply performing a tail -f of catalina.out allowed me to find this out.